# Android-ndk - simple build script for ndk-build for cygwin

Tags: android, bash, cygwin, android-ndk

I'm trying to make a simple build script that would work on windows and unix systems.
The script is to be run from cygwin if windows, otherwise just a standard shell.

The script will do the following:

1. set the directory variable SDK_ROOT to '/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~2/Android/android-sdk/'
2. set the directory variable NDK_ROOT to '/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~2/android-ndk-r6b'
3. cd Android/bin/
4. run javah -d ../../test/mytest/ -classpath .:$SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/android.jar com.test.MyTest
5. cd ..
6. run $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build

I'm not sure what kind of scripting language to use nor its syntax, I only know it would roughly look like above. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that you already wrote the script, it just needs a few modifications:

***Windows*** 
`myscript.cmd`

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

SET SDK_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\
SET NDK_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~2\android-ndk-r6b\
CD Android/bin/
javah -d ../../test/mytest/ -classpath .:%SDK_ROOT%/platforms/android-8/android.jar com.test.MyTest
CD ..
RUN %NDK_ROOT%/ndk-build

endlocal
```

***Unix***
`myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
SDK_ROOT="/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~2/Android/android-sdk/"
NDK_ROOT="/cygdrive/C/PROGRA~2/android-ndk-r6b"
cd Android/bin/
javah -d ../../test/mytest/ -classpath .:${SDK_ROOT}/platforms/android-8/android.jar com.test.MyTest
cd ..
$NDK_ROOT/ndk-build
```

Also, make sure that javah exists in your PATH env variable.
if it doesn't exist, you can add it to the scripts at the beginning: 
*Windows* 
`SET PATH=c:\path\to\javah;%PATH%` 
*Unix*
`export PATH=/path/to/javah:$PATH`

Note: you might have to modify the sdk/ndk paths for the script on windows.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for! However, when trying to run the unix-script in Cygwin; I am getting the following: #1: "line 5: $'\r': command does not exist."    #2: "No such file or directory: Android/bin/ (even though it definately exists from where the script is)"

Comment: are you launching the script(unix) from a bash cygwin shell? can you show me a screenshot please?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan The `\r` suggests there's a Windows "linefeed" character in the bash script. Try saving it with Unix-style line breaks. (e.g. In Notepad++: Edit menu, EOL Conversion)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Eclipse, I would suggest creating a new launcher for this task. Open up your project properties, and select Builders from the left pane. We want to end up with this:

[image: Project builders]

Click "New..." and create a new program launcher:

[image: New program launcher]

Fill in the path to `ndk-build` (I would suggest adding it to your system path so that you don't need an absolute path as depicted) and the project workspace:

[image: NDK builder properties]

This should already work, but we can restrict which resources are refreshed upon completion:

1. Click the "Refresh" tab
2. Check "Refresh resources upon completion"
3. Check "Specific resources"
4. Click "Specify resources"
5. Locate the `libs` folder in your project and select it (and any additional folders affected by the `ndk-build`, if applicable)

[image: Refresh working set]

Finally, we can restrict *when* NDK Builder should run (namely only when the JNI source changes):

1. Click the "Build options" tab
2. Check "Specify working set of relevant resources"
3. Click "Specify resources"
4. Locate the `jni` folder in your project and select it (or wherever you have the JNI source files, plus any additional files that should trigger a new `ndk-build`)

[image: Build options]

I hope this makes your build process easier!

Comment: I'm preferably looking for a .sh script solution that can be run independently of eclipse in cygwin

Comment: Hi @Paul this shows me error `Build Failed` in Eclipse.It gives this error `Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "D:\android-ndk-r5b\ndk-build" (in directory "D:\All Data\WorkSpace\MainBrowserActivity"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.Do have any solution

Comment: `ndk-build` is not a Windows executable. You can only run it on a Unix-based system or through Cygwin. The screenshots were taken on Windows, as here I'm running Eclipse from Cygwin. Normally I prefer to develop applications with native code under Ubuntu.

Comment: how u run eclipse from cygwin ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm missing something here. You can certainly run a shell script (.sh) on Windows via Cygwin or in Unix/Linux. Are you having specific problems?

Also, make sure you have the "#!/bin/bash" file prefix in your script.

Answer (score 0):

What about Ant? As far as I know, it can be run from Win as well as Linux ... and you'd have to code your targets only once for both. You could even put calls to Ant in a .bat and in a .sh if you insist.